# Spring Authorization Server userinfo endpoint

Tags: spring-security

I am getting the following output from the /userinfo endpoint

```
{
"sub": "XXXX@gmail.com",
"aud": [
    "XXXXXXXXX"
],
"nbf": 1646097620.000000000,
"scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email"
],
"iss": "https://XXXXXX/authServer",
"exp": 1646097920.000000000,
"iat": 1646097620.000000000
```

I need the username and the email to be visible.

Could any one help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working on reference documentation, including how-to guides for cases such as this one. See [How-to: Customize the OpenID Connect 1.0 UserInfo response #537](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/537), and feel free to up-vote that issue if it would be helpful to you.

In the meantime, check out the configuration in [OidcUserInfoTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/a661e1cdb7a77e3f2a1a0d958f8949896af66c6f/oauth2-authorization-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/authorization/OidcUserInfoTests.java#L290) which demonstrates how to customize the claims returned by the User Info endpoint. For example, you can simply map all of the claims from the JWT (access token), or you can map only specific claims.

You may also be interested in seeing the [DefaultOidcUserInfoMapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/a661e1cdb7a77e3f2a1a0d958f8949896af66c6f/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oidc/authentication/OidcUserInfoAuthenticationProvider.java#L134). The default strategy used is to map the standard claims from the `id_token` that are resolvable by the granted OIDC scope(s). Since in your example, you have `profile` and `email`, you can also provide an `OAuth2TokenCustomizer` to add the associated claims to the `id_token` when it is created, and they will automatically show up in the User Info endpoint. See [OidcTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/a661e1cdb7a77e3f2a1a0d958f8949896af66c6f/oauth2-authorization-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/authorization/OidcTests.java#L341-L353) for an example of customizing the `id_token`.